# Openshift portforwarding to remote access MySQL database

Tags: ssh, mysql, port-forwarding

So a followup to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056763/cannot-remote-access-mysql-database-of-my-openshift-mysql-cartridge

I've tried port-forwarding as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749599/openshift-how-to-remote-access-mysql but when I try `rhc port-forward -a myapp` it gives me an error:

> Error trying to forward ports. You can try to forward manually by running:
>   ssh -N blabla@myapp.rhcloud.com

So when I execute the command it gives me another error:

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/.ssh/known_hosts).
>   Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I tried adding my host to the known_hosts file but apparently I don't have access to the file.

I've searched for a solution and came accross this post which has the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113522/rhc-not-working-on-openshift-instance?ref=driverlayer.com/web but it doesn't get answered.

So I'm posting it again to find out why port-forwarding isn't working and how to fix this problem.

EDIT (extra info)

Executing `rhc setup` gives me an permission denied error at the generating a token step.

> Generate a token now? (yes|no) yes
>
> Generating an authorization token for this client ... /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/openshift/USER/.openshift (Errno::EACCES)

Executing `ls -l ~/.ssh/known_hosts` also gives me an permisson error

> ls: cannot access /var/lib/openshift/USER//.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied

Comment: A few questions:  Have you run rhc setup?  Does rhc ssh <app_name> work?  What are the permissions on your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file?  If rhc ssh does not work, try using the ssh -vvv command to get the verbose output of sshing to your gear.

Comment: I've added additional info, but why would I use rhc ssh <myapp> when I'm already ssh'ed into my app, and the -vvv doesn't seem to give any extra information

Comment: Yep, i figured that was your problem.  You need to run the rhc port forward command on YOUR computer, not on OpenShift...  You are forwarding ports FROM your computer TO OpenShift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after figuring out I had to port-forward on my local computer it still gave the same error.

But luckily I found the solution for me. I was pushing my work with sourcetree but it gave me an error that my private key wasn't loaded. So I loaded my private key in Pageant. After that I tried port-forwarding again, and to my surprise it did work.

When it worked I immediately removed the key from Pageant and no surprise, it gave me an error again when I tried to port-forward.

So all in all my problem was that I had to port-forward from my local machine and that I had to load my private key into Pageant.